# Guardar datos en una tabla pero a la vez editar o modificar datos de otra tabla diferente en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de guardar datos en la tabla *constancia_pro* pero a la vez quiero editar o modificar el campo *status* de "NO" a "SI" de la tabla *lpro_reg* al momento que yo le dé guardar, y me genera este error:

> The lpro_reg could not be changed because the data didn't validate.

*models.py*

```
class lpro_reg(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     tipodoc = (
         ('V', 'V'),
         ('E', 'E'),
         ('J', 'J'),
         ('G', 'G'),
     )
     tipo = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tipodoc, default='J')
     documento= models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
     presentante = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
     fecha_reg= models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     ramos = models.ManyToManyField(ciuu)
     direccion = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
     n_recibo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
     fecha_recibo = models.DateField()
     fecha_apert = models.DateField()
     opciones = (
         ('SI', 'SI'),
         ('NO', 'NO'),
     )
     status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=opciones, default='NO')
     responsable = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'prov_reg'
       ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)

class constancia_pro(models.Model):
    licencia2 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    n_constanica = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
    aprobado = models.OneToOneField(lpro_reg, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_reg = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'pro_const'
       ordering = ['-licencia2']

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.licencia2)
```

*views.py*

```
verdatos = get_object_or_404(lpro_reg.objects, pk = id)
ultimodato = constancia_pro.objects.first()
ultima_id = int(ultimodato.n_constanica)

if request.method == 'POST':
    
    formulario = aprobado_form(request.POST)
    formulario2 = registroprovicional_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=verdatos)
    

    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.instance.n_constanica = ultima_id + 1
        formulario.instance.aprobado = lpro_reg.objects.filter(pk = id).first()
        formulario2.instance.status = 'SI'
        formulario2.save()
        formulario.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Se ha guardado correctamente')
        return redirect('/actividad_economica/')


return render(request, 'act_econ/aprobacion.html', {'info':verdatos})
```

Esperaba que se modificara el campo *status* de NO a SI al momento de yo darle al botón de aprobar o guardar.